# What is the best way to automate ORACLE scripts with Nolio?

Tags: oracle, plsql, automation, devops, nolio

we are using Nolio to automate executions of multiple .sql scripts in ORACLE database.
what is the best way to implement it if we have multiple schemas to run on?
any useful links or references to show this scenario will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: We use CARA integrated with sql*plus. We dont need an agent installed on each DB too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really dependent on the specific details of the scripts.  Some of them are better served by converting into CARA Actions, others can be called using the built-in Oracle script actions, others might need to be executed using plsql at the command line.

Another challenge you might face is capturing and parsing the output from the script's execution for any potential errors.

The best place to ask this question, as well as provide details, would be on the community forum for CARA.

Note, CA Release Automation (CARA) is the current name of the product that was formerly known as Nolio :)

Answer (score 0):

I am used Nolio for SQL automation using the SQLCMD.exe tool doing same for Oracle now using the command line. Just ensure you have scripts numbered and executed in order so that create table is executed before alter table.

Surprise to know the name is changed to CARA now